# ASIHTTPRequest and php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ios, post, asihttprequest

I know there are a lot of questions similar to this but I couldn't find ones that suit to me.

What I'm trying to do is take a photo or choose a photo from camera roll and upload this to server and insert that photo to mysql db.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"myURL/whatever.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);

[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"test.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    if (responseString == nil) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title:rStrg" message:@"msg:rStrg" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}];

[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

and the php is

```
<? 
$photo = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['name']));

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "id", "password");

$dbconn = mysql_select_db("mydb", $conn) or die("Unable to find database");

mysql_query("set names utf8");

$Query = "INSERT INTO `my_table` ('sellerNum', 'Photo', 'Name', 'Tel', 'Location', 'Menu', 'Additional') VALUES (NULL, '$photo', NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)";

$res = mysql_query($Query, $conn);
?>
```

and nothing happens.....

'Photo' is long BLOB
and I want to Insert 'image' from ios client which is UIImage

Is there anything I missed in the code?

Comment: long time I havn't write a php code, but I think the sql will insert a '$photo' (string) and not the image in your variable. with blob I would use a ? and setParameteratPosition(1, $photo) something like that, prepared statement as I remmber

Comment: so...except for the inserting..Is there anymore errors?